# Limsup of a infinite sum, inserting a factor inside the sum, is the exchange justified?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits, analysis

Is it true that for non-negative functions $f_{n,r}$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$ and $r \in [0,1)$ we have that
$$
\limsup_{r \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{r} \sum_{n \geq 0} f_{n,r} = 
\limsup_{r \rightarrow 0}\sum_{n \geq 0}  \frac{1}{r}  f_{n,r}?
$$
Clearly the statement is obvious if the sum is finite, but can something go wrong if the sum is infinite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is true due to linearity of summation.

If $\sum_{n \in \mathbb N} a_n$ converges, then
$$
c\sum_{n \in \mathbb N} a_n = \sum_{n \in \mathbb N} ca_n
$$
for any constant $c$. If $c$ and $a_n$ depended on some parameter $r$, the situation would be the same. So adding any kind of limit in front of the same object would give the same answer.